# Como puedo realizar una consulta de un mismo campo y separarlo por rangos?

Tags: java, mysql

Ejemplo de la tabla

```
cliente|num_Pago|fecha_Pago|importe
00001|501202479397|05/31/20|1500
00001|501051675889|05/31/20|1900
00001|501189625418|05/31/20|3780
00001|501106276063|05/31/20|4500
00001|501020278591|05/31/20|6491
00001|501119147194|05/31/20|8523
00001|501200813449|05/31/20|12350
00001|501200813449|05/31/20|16000
```

y necesito que se muetre:

```
Cliente|volumen_Pagos|1 a 2000|2001 a 3000|3001 a 4000|4001 a 5000|5001 a 7500|7501 a 10000|>12000 
      1|            8|       2|           |          1|          1|          1|           1|     2
```

Espere haberme dado a entender.
Saludos y de antemano gracias.

Comment: Qué has intentado?
Para el formato printf() va a ser muy util.

Comment: Bienvenido  , revisa [ask] agrega lo que has tratado, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

encontre una solucion - **no es la optima**-
-- cabe señalar que la opción optima es con pivotes --

pero espero te sirva:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    r.cliente,
    (SELECT count(*) from tabla1 WHERE importe<2000) AS '<2000',
    (SELECT count(*) from tabla1 WHERE importe BETWEEN 2001 AND 3000) AS '2001-3000',
    (SELECT count(*) from tabla1 WHERE importe BETWEEN 3001 AND 4000) AS '3001-4000',
    (SELECT count(*) from tabla1 WHERE importe BETWEEN 4001 AND 5000) AS '4001-5000',
    (SELECT count(*) from tabla1 WHERE importe BETWEEN 5001 AND 6000) AS '5001-6000',
    (SELECT count(*) from tabla1 WHERE importe >6000) AS '>6000'
FROM 
    tabla1 r
```